# Flattening null objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to flatten an object into a viewmodel.
These are the classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual string Company { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Address DestinationAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public virtual string Street { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string Province { get; set; }
    public virtual string State { get; set; }
    public virtual string PostCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

The object `Customer` is loaded with nHibernate and sometimes the `Address` (destination) is null cause there's no association in the database.

I noticed that the mapping was painfully slow so I downloaded the code and this some debugging.
I noticed that null properties or objects were throwing exceptions (NullReferenceException) so I changed my mapping doing something like this:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationCity, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => (source.DestinationAddress == null || source.DestinationAddress.City == null) ? string.Empty : source.DestinationAddress.City))
.ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationStreet, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => (source.DestinationAddress == null || source.DestinationAddress.Street == null) ? string.Empty : source.DestinationAddress.Street))
.ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationPostCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => (source.DestinationAddress == null || source.DestinationAddress.PostCode == null) ? string.Empty : source.DestinationAddress.PostCode))
.ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationCountry, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => (source.DestinationAddress == null || source.DestinationAddress.Country == null) ? string.Empty : source.DestinationAddress.Country))
.ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationProvince, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => (source.DestinationAddress == null || source.DestinationAddress.Province == null) ? string.Empty : source.DestinationAddress.Province))
.ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationState, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => (source.DestinationAddress == null || source.DestinationAddress.State == null) ? string.Empty : source.DestinationAddress.State))
```

With this solution everything works but I don't think it's particularly "elegant".
Another thing I've noticed is when I load a customer with a null address - for some strange reason - it's still quite slow compared to the object with the address set.

I was wondering if there's a better alternative.

PS:

I've tried to measure performances.
A fully loaded object takes an average of **00:00:00.0003993** to be loaded.
An object with some null properties  takes an average of **00:00:04.5745887**.

Comment: What probably work and look better here is either `NullSafe` extension or something more elaborate, like a custom `Option`/`Maybe` type. Although maybe there's something built-in into the AutoMapper that can handle such case...

Comment: How about you change your MapFrom to something like ... `source => source.DestinationAddress != null ? source.DestinationAddress.PostCode.GetValueOrDefault() : string.Empty`

Comment: Did you knew that if you flatten your ViewModel as `DestinationAddress Street`, `DestinationAddressCity`... Automapper will automap these flatten properties? [Flattening](https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Flattening)

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek: I've tried Option but it seems to be ignored.

Comment: @allo_man: I didn't know that. I started to investigate the problem cause I noticed poor performances in the mapping process. I'll try and see if your solution improves my situation.